# Pascal's Triangle Algorithm Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, code-analysis

Do you think the pseudocode below is correct for calculating pascal's triangle? What would its time and space complexity be like? and how can I calculate it?

```
pascal triangle(n){
    list<list<int>> triangle // double list saving the triangle




    triangle.get(0).add(1)
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(triangle.get(i-1).get(j)==null || triangle.get(i-1).get(j-1)==null)  
                triangle.get(i).add(1)
            else
                triangle.get(i-1).add(triangle.get(i-1).get(j)+triangle.get(i-1).get(j-1))

        }

    }

    print(triangle)
}
```

Comment: In each iteration you add an element to the list, so it looks like space and memory complexity will be related, won't they?

Comment: I just edited. It is related to the size n. The space complexity I believe would be log(n). But the running time is somewhat hard for me to comprehend because of the inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudocode looks like it makes sense.

**For the complexity**

Your algorithm is trying to calculate each number of the triangle once. If we let each calculation be constant time complexity then we are doing:

```
sum(i) (0 -> n)
```

*Please excuse the poor notation* **To clarify:**

If *n* is *6* then we are going to iterate *6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1* times. This actual complexity can be simplified to:

```
(n + 1) * (n/2)
```

effectively

```
O(n^2)
```

**Another way of looking at the complexity**

You are essentially doing the area of a triangle in iterations which is `b*h/2`. Well we know the height of Pascal's triangle to be *n*. The bottom of the triangle (or the base) has *n* numbers. Therefore, we are generating:

```
n^2/2
```

which has a complexity of *O(n^2)*